# dplyr rowwise mutate with custom function returns unexpected NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with two columns that I would like to combine into a single column using dplyr rowwise mutate and a custom function. Strangely for the second row matching a certain pattern (but not the first or subsequent) I get NA as a return value. Below is an example:

```
my.func <- function(alpha, beta) {
  if(!is.na(beta) & beta) {
    return("c")
  } else if(is.na(alpha)) {
    return(as.character(NA))
  } else if (alpha == "a") {
    return("a")
  } else if (alpha == "b") {
    return("b")
  } else {
    return(as.character(NA))
  }
}

tmp <- data.frame(obs = 1:7,
                  dt = c('2016-03-15 17:35:46','2016-03-15 18:45:47','2016-03-15 19:22:17','2016-03-15 19:23:45','2016-03-15 20:21:55','2016-03-15 21:20:10','2016-03-15 22:18:34'),
                  one = c(NA,"a","a","a","b","a","b"), two = c(NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))

tmp2 <- tmp %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(three = my.func(one, two))
```

This results in an NA in row three, column three, when for the row above, with the exact same input, it resulted in "a".

Comment: Do you meant the third printed row or the row with a rowname of "3"? The row with a rowname of "1" is the only NA value when i run it and that entirely expected. (And I think you are referring to column 5.) Time for a version check?

Comment: I have dplyr version 0.4.3.9001

Comment: I am really puzzeld about this. `mapply(my.func, tmp$one, tmp$two)` provides the correct result. And if you change the first `NA` it becomes right as well... Maybe it has something to do with `rowwise()`.

Comment: This reported issue seems to fit the anomolous results: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1908

Comment: @42- To clarify I meant the third row and the fifth column, which is called "three". Sorry for the confusion.
I have dplyr version 0.4.3. I will upgrade.
Thank you for your help

Comment: @Alex Yes, without the first row it produces the correct results.

Comment: @42- packageVersion("dplyr") only shows two decimals even after updating. My understanding of package naming conventions is MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH. What does .9001 indicate and how do I see it?

Comment: The development version is available at Github.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand exactly why your code does not work, but the following seems to do what you expect:

```
tmp2 <- tmp %>% mutate(three = mapply(my.func, one, two))

>tmp2

  obs                  dt  one   two three
1   1 2016-03-15 17:35:46 <NA>    NA  <NA>
2   2 2016-03-15 18:45:47    a FALSE     a
3   3 2016-03-15 19:22:17    a FALSE     a
4   4 2016-03-15 19:23:45    a FALSE     a
5   5 2016-03-15 20:21:55    b FALSE     b
6   6 2016-03-15 21:20:10    a  TRUE     c
7   7 2016-03-15 22:18:34    b FALSE     b
```